# How do I extract specific columns from google sheets to google doc using Google Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a Google Doc with dynamics fields tag like ***%Name% - %Date of Birth%*** that take the values from a google sheets in column A and B:

Screenshot of the sheet[image]

As you can see the values inside in the firsts 2 columns is the same and so there is no problem for my "%" tags in the google doc because it takes the same value.
The problem is for the others columns (C,D,E...) where the values on the google sheet are variables.

How can apply in the Google doc a tag that dynamically take the value of these entire columns with the variable values?

[image: Screenshot of the Doc]

**Result expected:**

[image]

In addition, how can I set in the script the columns with fixed values eg. (in yellow) and the columns with variables values eg. (in blue)?

And, in any case, the script not works if I filter the spreadsheet, why?

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your issue. So can I ask you about your question? 1. 1st image and 2nd image are the Spreadsheet and the current result of your script? 2. Can you provide the output result you expect?

Comment: Answer 1: The 1st image is the spreadsheet with the values that must be transferred on the gdoc (2nd image). Answer 2: I have provided the result expected at the end of the updated question

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. In order to know the template Document, can you provide the template Document before the script is run? By this, I would like to check your script.

Comment: This Is the template doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cYtyoBmEOv4ApnUBQDhkWs0W5WnsX9QkmfL5qE8fBLE/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the template Document. From your additional information, I have questions. 1. Your template Document uses the text enclosed by `%` as the replacement text. But in your script, `<<` and `>>` are used. How about this? 2. In your script, each row creates each Document. But in your expected result, all rows are put to one Document. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your script. How about this? 3. Can I ask you about your detail goal?

Comment: The script I have added in the question Is only an example taken from the web. It takes the values from a spreadsheet to a doc and so you can edit as you want in order to reach the goal I expect in the final screenshot. Only a doc naturally must be generated from the script. For the tag, you can use the format as you want.

Comment: Thank you for replying. At first, I would like to correctly understand about your goal. In your sample Spreadsheet, it seems that there is only one name. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. The firts 2 columns have the same values. The others change. In general I would that the script allow to generate fixed values and variables values, as the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to retrieve the values from Spreadsheet and put to the template Document. In your Spreadsheet, all values of columns of "A" and "B" are the same for all rows like `john` and `25/05/1998`. You want to create one Google Document by replacing the placeholder by the values from Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes correct. You are in the right way.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my understanding:

- You want to retrieve the values from Spreadsheet and put to the template Document.
- In your Spreadsheet, all values of columns of "A" and "B" are the same for all rows like `john` and `25/05/1998`.
- You want to create one Google Document by replacing the placeholder by the values from Spreadsheet.

  - The placeholder is enclosed by `%`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Flow:

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.
2. Create an object for putting to Google Document.
3. Copy a template Google Document.
4. Put the header values to the copied Document using the object.

   - In this case, the placeholder is replaced by the retrieved values.
5. Put the table values using the object.

   - In this case, the retrieved values are directly put to the table in the template Document.

#### Sample script:

Before you run the script, please set `templateGoogleDocumentID`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var templateGoogleDocumentID = "###";  // Please set the template Google Document ID.

  // 1. Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = activeSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  // 2. Create an object for putting to Google Document.
  var object = {headers: {}, table: {}};
  var headerRow = values.shift();
  object.headers[headerRow[0]] = values[0][0];
  object.headers[headerRow[1]] = Utilities.formatDate(values[0][1], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy/MM/dd");
  object.table = values.map(r => r.splice(2, 5));
  
  // 3. Copy a template Google Document.
  var copiedTemplateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateGoogleDocumentID).makeCopy();
  var docId = copiedTemplateDoc.getId();
  
  // 4. Put the header values to the copied Document using the object.
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  var body = doc.getBody();
  Object.keys(object.headers).forEach(h => body.replaceText(`%${h.toLowerCase()}%`, object.headers[h]));
  
  // 5. Put the table values using the object.
  // If the table rows of Google Document are less than that of Spreadsheet, the rows are added.
  var table = body.getTables()[0];
  var r = object.table.length - table.getNumRows();
  if (r > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
      var tr = table.appendTableRow();
      for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        tr.appendTableCell();
      }
    }
  }
  object.table.forEach((row, i) => (row.forEach((col, j) => (table.getCell(i, j).setText(col)))));
  doc.saveAndClose();
  
  // If you want to export the Google Document as PDF file, please use the following script.
  // var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(doc.getBlob());
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, please enable V8 at the script editor.

#### References:

- [getCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#getCell(Integer,Integer))
- [setText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#setText(String))

Comment: The script works but how can I edit the order of the fixed columns (A,B) and the variable columns (C,D,E). I mean if the columns with the fixed values are B,D,E,J and the columns with variables values are K,L,M,N,AH; where can I set them?

Comment: I need also that the script works for filtered values, not all the sheets.

Comment: @Dito Thank you for replying. I answered your question after I confirmed whether my understanding is correct. But your replying is new question. Also I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Because your new question is different from your this question and I cannot see the vision of your goal from your new question. This is due to my poor understanding. I deeply apologize for this. So, can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, I would like to think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Dito Thank you for replying. If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.

Comment: @Dito Thank you for replying. I answered your question after I confirmed whether my understanding is correct. If you want to change the question, please post it as new question. By this, it will help users including me think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: If you want, we can have a private chat to be faster.

Comment: @Dito I cannot use the private chat. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: If you see the end of the question there Is the final request.

Comment: @Dito Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. Could you please post your new question as new question? By this, it will help users think of your new question.

Comment: If the columns of the sheet, in our case, are not A & B but, for example C,F,G and the columns, in our case C,D,E are for example T,U,W... How can I edit the script for the range?

Comment: @Dito Thank you for replying. I answered your question after I confirmed whether my understanding is correct. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information. By this, it will help users including me think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad.

Comment: this is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025816/retrieve-values-from-spreadsheet-custom-columns-and-put-to-template-document