# Retrieve values from Spreadsheet custom columns and put to template Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script, in my Spreadsheet, retrieve all values of columns of "A" and "B" that are the same for all rows and retrieve all values of columns of "C","D" and "E" that are variables for all the rows. 
The script creates one Google Document by replacing the placeholder by the values from Spreadsheet. 
The placeholder is enclosed by %.
How to set, in the script, the columns if they change and so to set custom columns?

```
function myFunction() {
  var templateGoogleDocumentID = "###";  // Please set the template Google Document ID.

  // 1. Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = activeSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // 2. Create an object for putting to Google Document.
  var object = {headers: {}, table: {}};
  var headerRow = values.shift();
  object.headers[headerRow[0]] = values[0][0];
  object.headers[headerRow[1]] = Utilities.formatDate(values[0][1], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy/MM/dd");
  object.table = values.map(r => r.splice(2, 5));

  // 3. Copy a template Google Document.
  var copiedTemplateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateGoogleDocumentID).makeCopy();
  var docId = copiedTemplateDoc.getId();

  // 4. Put the header values to the copied Document using the object.
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  var body = doc.getBody();
  Object.keys(object.headers).forEach(h => body.replaceText(`%${h.toLowerCase()}%`, object.headers[h]));

  // 5. Put the table values using the object.
  // If the table rows of Google Document are less than that of Spreadsheet, the rows are added.
  var table = body.getTables()[0];
  var r = object.table.length - table.getNumRows();
  if (r > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
      var tr = table.appendTableRow();
      for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        tr.appendTableCell();
      }
    }
  }
  object.table.forEach((row, i) => (row.forEach((col, j) => (table.getCell(i, j).setText(col)))));
  doc.saveAndClose();

  // If you want to export the Google Document as PDF file, please use the following script.
  // var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(doc.getBlob());
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? You want to retrieve the values from the columns "A" to "E" in the data range of the active sheet. You want to put the retrieved values to the table in Google Document. Is my understanding correct? And also, can you add the information about the template Google Document to your question?

Comment: Yes. Correct. But I would to edit the script if I change the range of the columns on my sheet. Both for the columns A and B (with the fixed values) and C,D,E (with variables values).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about your situation.

Comment: It is very simple. The columns in the script are A, B, C, D, E. I would to edit them in the script with other columns.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still image your situation. When I could correctly understand about it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: What is your language?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand what you want to say. I apologize for this.

Comment: Don't worry. I hope in the help of another user.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize I couldn't help.

Comment: Don't worry. I hope in the help of another user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do the following:

- Copy certain rows to a Document template.
- Copy only some of the columns (you will specify their indexes manually).
- Some columns are "fixed data" and will replace some placeholders on the top of the document.
- Some columns are "variable data" and a table will be created with such data.
- Some "variable data" are dates that need to be formatted.
- The data is copied to a copy of the Document template, to a specified folder.

Depending on how you want to select the rows to copy to the template, there are two methods you can follow:

#### Method #1: Copying selected rows:

This method will create the document faster, but you have to manually select all rows you want to copy to the template, **one by one (excluding the headers row)**.

```js
function exportSelectedRows() {
  var templateGoogleDocumentID = "#########";  // Please set the template Google Document ID.
  var destinationFolderID = "#########"; // Please set the destination folder ID
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, activeSheet.getLastRow()).getValues()[0]; // Get header values
  var values = activeSheet.getActiveRangeList().getRanges().map(range => range.getValues()).flat(); // Get the values of the selected rows
  values.unshift(headers);
  var fixedColumns = [1, 3, 4, 9]; // Fixed column indexes: B, D, E, J  
  var variableColumns = [10, 11, 12, 13, 21, 33]; // Variable column indexes: K,L,M,N,V,AH
  var fixedValues = removeUnwantedColumns(fixedColumns, values).slice(0, 2); // Retrieve fixed values (only header and one row is needed)
  var varValues = removeUnwantedColumns(variableColumns, values).map(row => row.map(value => { // Retrieve variable values (dates are formatted)
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === "[object Date]") {
      return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(value), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy/MM/dd");
    } else return value;
  }));  
  // Create template copy:
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderID); // Get folder with specified destinationFolderID
  var copiedTemplateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateGoogleDocumentID).makeCopy(folder); // Copy template to destination folder
  var docId = copiedTemplateDoc.getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  var body = doc.getBody();
  for (var i = 0; i < fixedValues[0].length; i++) {
    body.replaceText(`%${fixedValues[0][i]}%`, fixedValues[1][i]); // Replace fixed data with placeholders
  }
  body.appendTable(varValues); // Insert new table to document
  var table = body.getTables()[0];
  table.removeFromParent(); // Remove old table
}

function removeUnwantedColumns(columnsToKeep, values) {
  return values.map(row => row.filter((col, i) => columnsToKeep.includes(i)));
}
```

#### Method #2: Copying filtered rows:

In this method, the execution will take more time, specially if the sheet has many rows, but there is no need no manually select the rows, the filter handles this.

The script is almost like the one from method #1, but you would have to replace this line:

```js
var values = activeSheet.getActiveRangeList().getRanges().map(range => range.getValues()).flat(); // Get the values of the selected rows
```

With this one:

```js
var values = activeSheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter((row, i) => !activeSheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + 1)); // Remove filtered data
```

#### Notes:

- You should manually define the indexes of (1) fixed columns (`fixedColumns`), (2) variable columns (`variableColumns`) and (3) variable columns with date to be formatted (`formatDateColumns`).
- You should manually specify the `templateGoogleDocumentID` and the `destinationFolderID` in your code (check inline comments).
- The sheet headers should match the placeholder values in the document for this to work, including case (in the copy you shared, for example, the placeholder was written like `Codice FIscale`, instead of `Codice Fiscale`).
- The table columns are not getting copied according to any placeholder, but according to their relative position in the sheet. Headers are being copied too.
- Instead of checking whether the table dimensions match the data dimensions, I think it's better to create a new table with the right dimensions and remove the old one.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211363/discussion-on-answer-by-iamblichus-retrieve-values-from-spreadsheet-custom-colum).

Comment: With the method 1, when i will do the filter and then I drag the selection of rows from the header to bottom, the script generates the doc with all the rows. If i select one row at a time, it works but selecting one row at time is very annoying. It is possible simply dragging from the header to bottom the selection of the rows?   P.S. Can you delete the screen?

Comment: @Dito No, you are asking for something that is not possible. Dragging from header to bottom selects all rows in the sheet, disregarding whether they are filtered out or not. That's why I said you have to select the rows one by one. The only other option is method 2. You have to choose between speed and comfort, you cannot have both, I'm sorry. I'll delete the screenshot now.

Comment: Ok. i understand. Can you exclude to select the header? It have not sense.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @Dito you're welcome. I'll update my answer on Monday.

Comment: Ok. When you edit it, give me the possibility to set the font size of the doc generated. :)

Comment: @Dito I updated the script so that the headers doesn't have to be selected. About your other request, it doesn't have anything to do with the original question, so I'd suggest you to (1) do a bit of research about font sizes and formatting in general and (2) if after doing your research you have doubts on how to proceed, post a new question.